# Coral Dev Board Mini - Cannot connect through USB but device is listed [Ubuntu]

Tags: google-coral

I very recently got myself a Dev Board Mini and I cannot connect to the board using the command `mdt shell` as explained in the tutorial on Google Coral's website.

Since first connection, I have been able to see the device as listed by

```
> mdt devices
purple-snail        (192.168.100.2)
```

when I want to connect I get:

```
> mdt shell
Waiting for a device...
Connecting to purple-snail at 192.168.100.2
Looks like you don't have a private key yet. Generating one. (only appears first time, so key is generated)
Couldn't establish ssh connection to device: socket error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

As I am running on a dualboot, **I tried to connect with Windows and it worked perfectly**...

I really don't know why it does not work and I could not find similar issues where device was listed but connection failed.

Ubuntu version:

```
> lsb_release -a              
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**Other things I have tried but did not work:**

1. Using the MacOS proposed solution

```
> screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
[screen is terminating]
```

2. SSH into the board

```
> ssh mendel@192.168.100.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.2 port 22: Connection timed out
```

3. Use both bash or zsh (default for me)

Answer (score 0):

Humnn, that oddly seems like a libusb error from your linux OS side of things. One thing you can do is to try connecting to the board via wifi instead to confirm this.

1. Connect board to the internet with nmtui
2. Check the board's wlan0 ip address using `ip addr`
3. ssh:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key mendel@ip-addr
```

Comment: Thanks ! Weirdly enough, it works now using WiFi. In the mean-time, I followed this tutorial to install openssh-server (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-openssh-server/) and it now works. I don't know if it is thanks to this toturial or something  else I did... but specifying the key does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you read the google documentation, when you first connect to the board, it make a key for that connection (you windows connection)

If you want to connect using another computer (or os), you need to generate and push a new key.
There is documentation on how to do that, and i think you need to connect via serial